# at / in / in the - daylight / twilight

Tags: definite-articles, zero-article

While most of the nouns denoting parts of the day are used either with "at.." or "in the.." prepositions (**in the** morning / afternoon / evening / daytime; **at** nighttime / noon / night / midday / midnight / dawn / dusk / sunrise / sunset / sundown / daybreak / nightfall)

**"daylight"** and **"twilight"** seem to go beyond the dichotomy:

**At daylight** on the 7th of October 1813 he crossed the Bidassoa...

**In daylight**, he was almost approachable.

Let us walk with decency, as **in the daylight**: not in carousing and drunkenness; not in sexual impurity and promiscuity; not in quarreling and jealousy.

..legions of these delicate minute flies fill the air **at twilight**..

We are always living **in twilight**..

..farmers starting for Boston **in the twilight**..

So what's the difference between the three patterns: "at N", "in N", "in the N"?

Answer (score 5):

***At*** *daylight* means the moment in time when daylight begins. “At midnight, the vampire arose. At daylight, the vampire exploded.”

***In*** *daylight* means bathed in the light of day. “In artificial light, vampires look pale. In daylight, vampires explode.”

Comment: Thank you, MετάEd, so, while


"at daylight" ~ "at dawn", 


"in the daylight"  could mean ~ "in the daytime"?

Comment: Examples testifying that "in the daylight" might mean "in the daytime": parallel translations of  Romans 13:13 [http://biblehub.com/romans/13-13.htm]  
as in the daytime,  
as in daytime,  
as in the day,  
as in the daylight

Comment: @KostyaHmelnitski Those are evidence the translators disagree on the meaning of the text, not evidence the two phrases have the same meaning.

Comment: @KostyaHmelnitski "In the daylight" is not the same as "in the daytime". It can be daytime even in a cave where no daylight reaches you. So you might be doing something in the daytime but not in the daylight.